# i need help for simple C program

Tags: c

i made a program to calculate multiples of 5 between two numbers, when ask for de second numbers the program didn't work normally.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A, B, cont;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Indique el dominio de los numeros en los que desa saber cuales son multiplos de 5\n");
    printf("Primer numero: \n");
    scanf("%i",&A); 
    printf("Segundo numero: \n");
    scanf("%i",&B); 
    if (A < B){
        A = B;
        //B = A;
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Los multiplos de 5 comprendidos entre %i y %i son; \n",A,B);
    cont = 0;
    while(A < B){
        if (A % 5 == 0)
            cont++; 
            A++;    
        }
        if (cont > 0) 
            printf("Entre los numeros %i y %i hay un total de %i multiplos de 5.\n",A,B,cont);
        else
            printf("El intervalo no se encuentran multiplos de 5.\n");      
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic. Compile your code with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) then use the debugger

Comment: `scanf("i%",&A);`--> `scanf("%i",&A);`

Answer (score 5):

You have the format backwards

```
scanf("i%",&A);
```

should be

```
scanf("%i",&A);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your swapping logic is wrong. Use another variable to do it correctly.

```
int t = A;
A = B;
B = t;
```

Also you would want to swap when `A` is greater than `B`.

```
if( A > B ){
  /* swap*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A, B, cont=0;
    printf("Program to find the Multiples of 5\n");
    printf("First Number \n");
    scanf("%d",&A); 
    printf("Second Number \n");
    scanf("%d",&B); 
    system("cls");
    printf("The Multiples of 5 between %d and %d \n", A,B);
    if(A<B){
    while(A <= B){
        if (A % 5 == 0)
            {
              cont++;
            } 
            A++;    
        }
    }
    else 
    {
    while(A >=B){
        if (A % 5 == 0)
            {
              cont++;
            } 
            A--;    
        }
    }
     if (cont > 0) 
            printf("The total Multiples of 5 between %d and %d are %d\n",A,B,cont);
        else
            printf("No Multiple of 5 exists between %d and %d\n",A,B);      
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I try to solve each case. If user enter A>B then your code fails but it works